# Is the definite article required?

Tags: articles

> "%40 of population is fat."

as opposed to:

> "The %40 of population is fat."

I know the definite article is used when referring to specific things but where and how could I make this distinction.

Comment: I think the only time you'd reference a specific percentage using the definite article is in contexts where *that same percentage* has already been identified earlier. For example, *40% of the population consume more energy than they use. Unsurprisingly, the 40% is fat*. But that's a weird contrived context, and I suspect it's impossible to even *contrive* a context where you'd also qualify that percentage as *40% of **the** population* (note that without *that* article, the words are simply ungrammatical).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, do you mean a context like, "the 40% of the population *that* is fat"?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: protest groups talk about _the 1%_, because you're supposed to know what they mean.

Answer (score 8):

In this case, the definite article should go before "population", since this is what you are specifying. The percentage is what is describing the specific subject.

Also, the "%" goes after the number. So:

> 40% of the population is fat.

Although this is more style than grammar, starting a sentence with a number is typically avoided in formal English. So, you could also write it as:

> Forty percent of the population is fat.

Although, if this is formal, I would also avoid the word "fat" in favor of something more precise and scientific.

Answer (score 6):

A definite article is required, but not where you've used it. It should be "40% of *the* population is fat."

There can be many populations, but you should use "the" to indicate you're referring *to a specific one*.